# Detecting exactly 1 player in radius

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to detect if exactly **1** player is in a radius using `testfor`. To my understanding, I should be able to use the `c` argument to count players, but I am having no such luck.

```
/testfor @e[x=0,y=0,z=0,r=100,c=1]
```

The intended output of this command is to return `true` if exactly 1 players is within 100 blocks of `0,0,0`, and `false` if not.

If it makes any difference, testing for less than 2 players would solve my problem as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`c=X` will truncate the list down to `X` players. For example, if `@a` finds *Alice*, *Bob* and *Carol*, then `@a[c=2]` will find *Alice* and *Bob*.

The selector will still be successful so long as it finds at least one player, even though there were more players. This is similar to how other selector arguments such as `x=0,y=0,z=0,r=100` only need one player to match to be successful, not every player on the server.

---

To determine if there is exactly one player within a certain radius, you can use a command blocks' `SuccessCount`, which with `/testfor` will store how many players were detected. You can thus test when this is exactly one with a second command block, and have the conditions running off of that:

[image: Setup]

Commands:

```
1. /testfor @a[x=0,y=0,z=0,r=100]
2. /testforblock ~1 ~ ~ command_block * {SuccessCount:1}
3. commands you want to activate when exactly one player is within the radius
```

Keep in mind that you'll need to change `command_block` to match the type of command block the one with `testfor` in is (e.g: `chain_command_block` or `repeating_command block`), and `~1 ~ ~` to match where it is.

Comment: In the command block 2, I have the command `testforblock 4 64 -15 minecraft:repeating_command_block * {SuccessCount:1}`. This returns false even when command block 1 has found exactly one player. Command block #1:` testfor @e[x=0,y=0,z=0,r=1000]`. I have verified that the coordinates are correct, as well as the type of command block.

Comment: It appears that the first command block is ALWAYS returning 0 as the `SuccessCount`

Comment: @JulianLachniet What's the output message of the first command block?

Comment: `Found ilovescratch`

Comment: I would have recommended using dummy scoreboard objectives that are applied, tested, then removed <b>in that order</b> ... but as I have yet to understand how to do so, I am at a loss of creating an answer. One thing is certain with my idea: I do know it would involve a few more command block checks for "less than" and/or "greater than" the target number of players if the result needs it to be existing.

Comment: @JulianLachniet Is the time shown before that message updating?

Comment: Never mind. I think there was a bug somewhere causing the first command block not to be run. Replacing it fixed the glitch.

Comment: You can set the initial command to `/testfor @a[x=0,y=0,z=0,r=100,c=2]` to stop the `/testfor` command from iterating more than is needed (as you only need to know if there are 0, 1, or more players). You could also set the second command block to conditional since it doesn't need to activate unless 1+ players were found.